# AttributeError: module 'ale_py.gym' has no attribute 'ALGymEnv'

Tags: python, openai-gym

'Does anyone have any idea about how to handle this problem, I run the code in the Jupiter notebook, I tried few different things, but cannot find a suitable solution for this problem '

```
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 

#create the environment
env_name="Breakout-v0"

env =gym.make(env_name)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1d1ff99ad89f> in <module>
----> 1 env =gym.make(env_name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)
    198 
    199 def make(id, **kwargs):
--> 200     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
    201 
    202 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
    103             logger.info("Making new env: %s", path)
    104         spec = self.spec(path)
--> 105         env = spec.make(**kwargs)
    106         if env.spec.max_episode_steps is not None:
    107             from gym.wrappers.time_limit import TimeLimit

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, **kwargs)
     72             env = self.entry_point(**_kwargs)
     73         else:
---> 74             cls = load(self.entry_point)
     75             env = cls(**_kwargs)
     76 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in load(name)
     16     mod_name, attr_name = name.split(":")
     17     mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
---> 18     fn = getattr(mod, attr_name)
     19     return fn
     20 

AttributeError: module 'ale_py.gym' has no attribute 'ALGymEnv'
```

Comment: `Error: We're Unable to find the game "Breakout". Note: Gym no longer distributes ROMs. If you own a license to use the necessary ROMs for research purposes you can download them via `pip install gym[accept-rom-license]`. Otherwise, you should try importing "Breakout" via the command `ale-import-roms`. If you believe this is a mistake perhaps your copy of "Breakout" is unsupported. To check if this is the case try providing the environment variable `

Comment: `PYTHONWARNINGS=default::ImportWarning:ale_py.roms`. For more information see: https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment#rom-management`             I got these error messages after updating, I think it will no longer available

Answer (score 1):

Check if your ale-py has a version ale-py=0.7.1. downgrade to ale-py=0.7.

Comment: okay, i will try that

Comment: I've downgraded the ale_py library to 0.7 but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally resolved the problem reading the issue in Github: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2441

You only have to update Gym with `pip install -U gym`.